# Ошибка Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: python, discord.py, yt-dlp

Делаю Discord-бота (**discord.py**) на `python`. Добавляю функцию воспроизведения музыки:

```
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl

...

@bot.slash_command(name='играть', description='Проигрывать музыку с Youtube')
async def play(ctx, url:  Option(str, description='Введите url', required=True)):

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected:
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()


        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
            'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
            'option': '-vn',
        }


        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=url))
```

Ещё не очень разбираюсь в библиотеке `yt-dlp`, но файл `ffmpeg.exe` скачал в папку с проектом. Вылезает ошибка:

```
[youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKJxLspjgIg
[youtube] NKJxLspjgIg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NKJxLspjgIg: Downloading ios player API JSON
[youtube] NKJxLspjgIg: Downloading android player API JSON
[youtube] NKJxLspjgIg: Downloading m3u8 information
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKJxLspjgIg: Invalid data found when processing input
```

И так при каждом `url`. Подскажите, если есть более простые варианты кода и помогите разобраться с ошибкой. Спасибо заранее :)